# Wrap a element if parent doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, html

Hi there I would like to develop a simple code that will allow me to wrap a parent element if that element doesn't exist. Many thanks in advance!

Before:

```
<div class="wrapper"><img src="#"></div>
```

After:

```
<div class="wrapper"><figure><img src="#"></figure></div>
```

**Update: 
I think what I need is an if statement that would be able to identify whether the  tag has a . If it has it than do not add it, but if it doesn't than add it. Hopefully that is more clear.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use find all the `img` [Child Selector ("parent > child")](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) then use [`$.fn.wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

```
 $('.wrapper > img').wrapAll('<figure />');
```

As per comments, I think you need this

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    if (_this.parent('figure').length == 0) {
      _this.wrap('<figure >');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="#" />
</div>
<img src="#" />
```

Comment: Now suppose the .wrapper isn't there, could you help me in writing an if or and statement that would say that if an img doesn't have <figure> as a parent -add it.

Comment: @RyanPerez, Sure I will help you but please elaborate so that we can understand your exact problem

Comment: @RyanPerez, I have modified code snippet check if thats what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use immediate child selector `>` to target img elements that are direct child of div. Then use `.wrap()` with figure element:

```
$('div > img').wrap('<figure></figure>');
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sv0xze3z/)**

Answer (score 1):

To check if the `img` has parent `.wrapper` you can use `each` to loop over all the images and check if `parent` is `.wrapper`.

```
$('img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('wrapper')) {
        $(this).wrap('<figure />');
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/sv0xze3z/1/